# Where can I find actual specs for Imgur api?

Tags: imgur

I'm trying implement Imgur API, but facing with problem. Data models present in https://api.imgur.com/models have wrong optional/non-optional attributes.

I know, that Imgur API has new docs at https://apidocs.imgur.com , but links on Response Models follow to old docs.

For example: [Image model](https://api.imgur.com/models/image)

Seems like that `title` field is non-null, but it can be equal `null` in a response. Is this object invalid? Should I reject this object?

Answer (score 0):

When I arrive at the link above, I get a notification to go the new documentation site @ http://apidoscs.imgur.com.

[image: Notification to use new imgur docs]

Are you perhaps viewing the old site?

Comment: Yep, but links to data models from new docs https://apidocs.imgur.com/ follow to old site https://api.imgur.com . For example, you can open new docs, follow to album section and open specs for Album Response Model